# Two dimensional array which have CSV::Row object returns different result in ruby 2.3 and ruby 2.6

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.3, ruby-2.6

Two dimensional array has the element which is CSV::Row object like this.

[[csv_row_object]]

I tried to flatten this array and got different result in ruby 2.3 and 2.6.

why different result?

```
# in Ruby 2.6(ruby 2.6.0rc1)

[[#<CSV::Row "no":"001111" "status":"1" >]].flatten

returns ["no","001111","status","1"]


# in Ruby 2.3.8

[[#<CSV::Row "no":"001111" "status":"1">]].flatten

returns [#<CSV::Row "no":"001111" "status":"1">]
```

Comment: Can you post the code you're using to load the CSV? I don't see this behavior when calling `CSV.read` with `headers: true`

Comment: I don't think your first result could possibly be correct. After all, if `obj` is not an array `[[obj]].flatten #=> [obj]`, regardless of whether `obj` is a CSV row object or something else.

Comment: In ruby 2.6, [[#<CSV::Row "no":"001111" "status":"1" >]].flatten(1) returns [#<CSV::Row "no":"001111" "status":"1">]. CSV::Row object is not an array.so i expect that  [[#<CSV::Row "no":"001111" "status":"1" >]].flatten returns [#<CSV::Row "no":"001111" "status":"1">]  but doesn't.

Comment: I reproduced the first result (v2.6.0rc1) using v2.7.0. I would think the second result (v2.3.8) is correct and the first result is due to a bug, but I can't mind-read the Ruby monks' intent. I did notice that the C code for `Array#flatten` differs between the two versions, but I'm not quite up to digging though it. I'll look at it tomorrow and at a minimum post some example data and code, and some thoughts on the subject. Interesting.

Comment: I reported bug issue below.
https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/15967

This is Known issue. 

Kouhei Sutou said 
"It's introduced by #10013.
Adding CSV::Row#to_ary may be wrong. But I couldn't remove CSV::Row#to_ary to avoid compatibility breakage again."